# Combining for-loops in the same line python without changing the object type in the dict

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, for-loop, copy

I would like to copy a dictionary, which have pandas dfs inside, without using the `deepcopy()` function of the `copy` module.

example:

```
dict = {'a': {1: pd.Dataframe(...), 2: pd.Dataframe(...)}

copy_dict = {'a': {i: v.copy() for i in dict for v in dict.values()}}
```

Above works however it converts the dfs into bound method. What I want is to not convert the dataframe object.

In the `copy_dict` the df is converted to the following:

```
<bound method NDFrame.copy of                            DEtoDK  DKtoDE
2021-01-01 00:00:00+00:00    2500    2500
2021-01-01 01:00:00+00:00    2500    2500
2021-01-01 02:00:00+00:00    2500    2500
2021-01-01 03:00:00+00:00    2500    2500
2021-01-01 04:00:00+00:00    2500    2500
...                           ...     ...
2021-05-31 19:00:00+00:00    2280    2500
2021-05-31 20:00:00+00:00    2500    2360
2021-05-31 21:00:00+00:00    2500    2170
2021-05-31 22:00:00+00:00    2500    2280
2021-05-31 23:00:00+00:00    2500    2310

[3624 rows x 2 columns]>

type(copy_dict['a'])
method
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
copy_dict = {k_outer: 
    {k_inner: v_inner.copy() for k_inner, v_inner in v_outer.items()} 
    for k_outer, v_outer in dict.items()
}
```

Note: don't use `dict` (for that matter any python built-in function names) as variable name.

To modify it for special case (eg. apply only to key `'a'`):

```
copy_dict = {'a': 
    {k: v.copy() for k, v in dict['a'].items()} 
}
```

Comment: this works, but can you simplify it for me. Imagine I got only one key in dict which is a. I do not want to apply this to all the other keys, since it brokes the other dict items. Meanwhile I will accept the answer in 4mins. (Basically if I apply this to all other keys, if a key has only df inside instead of a dict, then this converts the df into 2 different series object)